# Сумма всех значений в объектах

Tags: javascript

```
  {
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "1663.00",
    "summv": "1139.04",
  },
  {
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "232.00",
    "summv": "111.24",
  },
  {
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "18189.00",
    "summv": "11779.37",
  },
```

Как посчитать сумму всех значений `summ_p` в объектах ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "1663.00",
    "summv": "1139.04",
  },
  {
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "232.00",
    "summv": "111.24",
  },
  {
    "data": "2021-02-01 20:00:00",
    "summ_p": "18189.00",
    "summv": "11779.37",
  }];

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + (parseFloat(item.summ_p)), 0).toFixed(2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: неужели обогнал! :D

Comment: @teran да, только чуть поторопился ;-)

Comment: там же не сказано было, в каком именно виде сложить :D пофиксил, спс )

Comment: @teran %) кстати, не всегда корректно будет... например если вместо `summ_p` подставить `summv` - то будут особенности работы с чисел с плавающей точкой))  Поэтому я тут parse и tofixed и использовал))

Answer (score 1):

видимо так

```
let result = data.reduce((acc,v) => +v.summ_p + acc, 0);
```

Comment: я убрал минус, но при некоторых числах с плавающей точкой будет сюрприз )